# Need to use dnscmd to modify the ttls of a list of records

Tags: dns, ttl

I have a list of records that all need their individual TTLs modified.  I can't seem to find a way with this odd syntax to do so, however.  Any recommendations?  Would I have to delete them all and then re-add after with the correct settings?

I can't seem to find a "modifyrecord" option unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

The question as written doesn't make sense - what "odd syntax", for example?  What DNS software?

In any event, the *standard* way to change the DNS records on a running server is to use DNS Dynamic Updates ([RFC 2136](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136)).

If on the other hand you're talking about Microsoft's `dnscmd` utility then:

1. this should probably be on https://serverfault.com/
2. with `dnscmd` you do indeed have to delete the record and add it again